# Singleton Factory Member Function Thread Safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton, thread-safety, factory

I want a singleton factory that generates IPropertyMapper objects. The factory has a dictionary which holds references to Func delegates.  The dictionary is immutable, i just want fast access.  Will this code below be thread-safe? Is calling Create() thread safe?

class definition:

```
public sealed class PropertyMapperFactory
    {
        private static readonly PropertyMapperFactory _instance = new PropertyMapperFactory();

        private readonly Dictionary<int, Func<TResult>> _handlers;

        private PropertyMapperFactory() {
            this._handlers = new Dictionary<...>();
            this._setTimeHandler();
        }

        public static PropertyMapperFactory GetFactory() {
            return _instance;
        }

        //Is this thread safe?
        public IPropertyMapper Create(UnitSetting _units ) {
            return new PropertyMapper(this.handler[0])
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type is generally regarded as safe to *read* from concurrent threads, but that all write operations must be completely isolated (no other writes--or reads--at the same time). If you aren't modifying the dictionary at any time after construction, then you should be OK.

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks for your response. My delegate function is defined as such: Func<object, string> ((target)=>{return target.toString()});.  Will my delegate also be executed on the current thread stack? Since this is a shared variable/function ptr does it require sync primitives?

Comment: @Amit: If you have separate unrelated questions, please post separate questions. Don’t ask unrelated questions in a comment.

Comment: @Timwi: Hey Tim, they are related to my solution. I am continuing my line of questioning on the premise of thread-safety with a singleton that holds a hash of delegates. The above code may not convey it, but the reference to handler[0] is set in ProperyManager, which is then used by the thread which called the singleton's Create() function.

Comment: @Amit: Invoking a delegate is no different (from a call stack perspective) than invoking any other function. If you invoke it using the `Invoke` function (or by just affixing parens to the end of the variable and invoking it directly), then it will run on the current call stack--just like any other function. If you invoke it with `BeginInvoke`, it will (probably, but not definitely) use the `ThreadPool` to invoke, so it would be on a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never change the values in the dictionary after the constructor completes, that's fine. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` supports multiple readers, so long as there aren't any writers.